# How to get div id, if i have descendent href?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How can I extract `div#id` through descendent's link href?

I tried to use `XPATH` and get parents elements by `..//.`
But no. Help please!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Please supply more context (and perhaps some code).  I know that selenium has bindings for several languages.  What language are you writing in?

Comment: c#. `cdHandler.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/a[@href = 'linkExample']..//")).GetAttribute("class")`
But it is incorrect Xpath

Comment: this is not more context, add the more code you tried , what error you getting and what you are trying, what you are expecting to happen,with error stack trace

Comment: Also, have you considered a different approach to your problem?  Perhaps selecting an anchor element by it's href is not the most direct approach.  This may help: https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there.

As per your code trials through:

```
cdHandler.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/a[@href='linkExample']"));
```

You have located the *descendent* node. Now to traverse up to the *ancestor* `<div>` node you can use `..` as follows:

```
cdHandler.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/a[@href='linkExample']/.."));
```

Finally, to extract the **id** attribute of the *ancestor* `<div>` node you can use:

```
cdHandler.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/a[@href='linkExample']/..")).GetAttribute("id");
```